# mplfinance plot plots correctly but has strange datetime format

Tags: pyqt5, mplfinance

I am plotting stock data with mplfinance and it works well. But I am having trouble getting the right dates from the x-axis. When I use this code the function on_mouse_click shows results like 1970-02-02 and 65.6. The 65.6 is obviously right, but I am plotting data from 2022 and 2023. I tried several ways with DateFormatters etc. but I think it is a question of set_xlim. or something else. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=300):        
        self.fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, 
                                    gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [4, 1]})
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0)
        plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
        self.ax = ax[0]
        self.volax = ax[1]
        
        
        super().__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_mouse_click)
        
        
    def on_mouse_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 3: # Right mouse button
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            date_str = mdates.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            msg = f'Datum: {date_str}\nPrice: {y:.2f}'
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Mouse Position', msg)
```

Comment: What is the `x` range? Does it use discrete numbers to represent days in the solar year? Because if that's the case, you should update the *epoch*: as the documentation about [`num2date()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) shows, it defaults to [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so either update `rcParams` or use `set_epoch`. Otherwise, if it's in the 0-1 range, you should convert it by multiplying the number of days in that year: 2022 was not a leap year, so it should be `round(365 * x)`.

Comment: The x-Range is from April 2022 until today. I am preparing the data as such:```def getData(self, iisin):
        data = pd.read_csv(pfad, header=0, sep='|', encoding='utf-8')
        data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Datum'])
        data = data.set_index('Date', drop = False)
        return data

Comment: Sorry but your answer is unclear, and there's also no mention about that data in your question. If you're using the default plot range (0, 1), do as written above, otherwise please provide a valid [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mplfinance to plot the data, without setting `show_nontrading=True`, then your right-click date-display transformation is incorrect.

You have two choices, either one of which should work to fix this, but not both together:

1. Set `show_nontrading=True` when calling mplfinance.
2. Modify your transformation as follows ... note the conversion of `x` to `xdate` and calling `.strftime()` directly on `xdate`.  I have assumed that `self.df` is the DataFrame that you pass into mplfinance, but if not, then find that DataFrame and use the DataFrame.DatetimeIndex to convert `x` to `xdate`.

```py
    def on_mouse_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 3: # Right mouse button
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            # --- modified code here:
            xdate = self.df.index[int(x)]
            date_str = xdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            # --- until here ---
            msg = f'Datum: {date_str}\nPrice: {y:.2f}'
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Mouse Position', msg)
```

For more information read [Mplfinance Time Axis Concerns ...](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Mplfinance-Time-Axis-Concerns,-and-Internals-of-Displaying-or-Not-Displaying-Non-Trading-periods)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! Even when zooming in or moving the candle chart your solution delivers the correct date. I must admit that you have just become my new hero now ;-)